# Adobe AIR - Output a Mac installer on Windows

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

Is it possible to output an Adobe Air app Mac installer from Flash CS5 on Windows? I only see an option for a Windows .exe and not for a .dmg file.

Maybe anybody knows of a 3rd party tool for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you are talking about native installers, then you're out of luck.  native installers must be created on the target OS.  it's the same for Flash CS5 on Mac, where we only have the option to make a .dmg native installer.

creating a native installer is possible, and fairly simple, using the AIR SDK and the command line.  instructions are readily found online.  if you have access to a mac all you need is your compiled .swf, your assets and a copy of the free AIR SDK and you can make one in no time without having to install Flash CS5 for Mac.

Comment: I've used Flash Builder to build a cross platform installer on my Mac that installs the app on either Windows or Mac.

Comment: @jeremynealbrown A native installer or a .air file?

Comment: It is a .air file that can install the app on either platform.

Comment: @jeremynealbrown, there is a difference between an .air file and a AIR native installer, including limitations of some APIs like NativeProcess.